# AngularJS submit json

Tags: json, angularjs

Here is a form with angularjs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="formController">
  <form novalidate>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName"><br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastName">
    <br><br>
    <button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
  </form>
  <p>form = {{user }}</p>
</div>

<script>
function formController ($scope) {
    $scope.master = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe"};
    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };
    $scope.reset();
}
</script>

</body>
```

I am not familiar with AngularJS, I found the expression {{user}} display as a json like format data which was binded to the textbox. I want to know is there any way to post {{user}} as json directly to the server side. I know I can easily post the form. But my purpose is the page may have a lot of textbox. I want to store it using json, just like {{user}} and submit as a combined one. 
And I also want to know how to remove one value in the expression. i.e. the following code has two attribute firstName and lastName. Is there a way like remove(), after call it. I can remove one attribute in the correspond json data.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can post your modal (user in this case) directly as JSON using $http .

In case all you text fields are saved in the user modal then u can remove one of the attributes by calling the below function before submitting the form

```
    $scope.remove = function (user) {
    delete $scope.user.firstName;//the output here is user with only lastname
    }
```